# Add arrow on one end of path without changing the other

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Is it possible to specify an arrow tip for one end of a path without overriding an existing specification for the other end?

I have noticed that this can be achieved (at least, at the end--but not the start--of a path, and using an older version of pgf?) by using an invalid arrow end type, but of course this gives an error. Is there an arrow shape that says "use the current default arrowhead or lack thereof", giving this behavior?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{arrowstart/.style={<-initial}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[->]
    \draw[arrowstart] (0,.2) -- +(1,0);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[|-|]
    \draw[arrowstart] (0,0) -- +(1,0);
  \end{scope}
  \draw[arrowstart] (0,-.2) -- +(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

should produce:

[image: arrows]

(Of course, if I know what the arrow at the other end should be then I can use the correct specification, but if I want to use the same style in several different scopes then this may not be practical.)

Comment: perhaps `\begin{scope}[->]
  \draw[<-] (0,1) -- (1,1);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
  \draw[<-] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{scope}`, where the top arrow should be of `<->` type and the bottom `<-` with the same `foo` in `\draw [foo]` in either case would make a clearer MWE/specification.

Comment: Probably you wan to set both arrow ends using `/.tip` in this way you can inherit it. For example if you set in the scope `[>/.tip={}, </.tip=latex, <-]` then you can use `stealth->` that will behave like `stealth-`.

Comment: @Kpym: Ah, thanks! Of course, that basically means I have to set all of my arrow tips that way, but it works! At least for single arrow tips. Is there a way to apply it for composite arrow tips like `>|`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a way to recover the current arrow, but you can define your `initial` arrow as empty by default, and redefine it in the scope.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2pt]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  initial/.tip = {},
  arrowstart/.style={<-initial}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[initial/.tip = {latex}, -initial, yshift=4mm]
      \draw[red] (0,2mm) -- +(1,0);
      \draw[arrowstart] (0,0) -- +(1,0);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[initial/.tip = {|}, initial-initial]
      \draw[red] (0,2mm) -- +(1,0);
      \draw[arrowstart] (0,0) -- +(1,0);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-4mm]
      \draw[red] (0,2mm) -- +(1,0);
      \draw[arrowstart] (0,0) -- +(1,0);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! Even better to define separate `arrowhead` and `arrowtail` tip styles (initially empty), with the entire picture using `arrowtail-arrowhead`. Then the two styles can be set independently throughout.